# How can filter this table based on a column's boolean value?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to filter a table based on whether or not my "projects" are active or not. I currently have a table, where "active" is a column and it will say either true or false based on the project status. I would like to be able to filter my table based on this boolean value.

So I am currently using a selection menu, which will return either true or false based on the selection. From what ive been trying, the table wont filter on boolean values, only on strings. So i have a filtered predicate that is trying to force the filtering only on my active column, however it is currently not working as intended.

```
//.ts file
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<OrderTemplateInterfaceWithId> = new MatTableDataSource([]);
  displayedColumns = [
    'dayOfWeek',
    'startTime',
    'endTime',
    'technician',
    'frequency',
    'startDate',
    'endDate',
    'active',
    'actions'
  ];

ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: OrderTemplateInterfaceWithId, filter: string) => {
      return data.active === (filter === "true") || data.active === (filter === "false");
    };
  }

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    console.log(this.dataSource);
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

//.html file
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select (selectionChange)="applyFilter($event.value)">
  <mat-option value='true'>Active</mat-option>
  <mat-option value='false'>InActive</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

So i would expect the results to have my table filtered by the active column based on my selection menu. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So figured out that I had to have my filterPredicate inside my applyFilter, right before I did the actual filter. So my applyFilter looked like:

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    if(filterValue === 'all') {
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter): boolean {
        return String(data.active).includes('true')
          || String(data.active).includes('false');
      };
    }
    else {
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter): boolean {
        return String(data.active).includes(filter);
      };
    }
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As simple like that:

FilterPredicate deffinition

```
ngInit(){
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate = (data: any, filter: string) => !filter || data.checked == Boolean(filter);
}
```

And the filter function is:

```
apllyfilter(){
    this.dataSource.filter = "true";
}
```